# asynchronous jquery script

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, asynchronous

i want to do the following little script/thing.
There's a registration form and i want jquery to check if the typed data (e.g. loginname and/or email adress) matches the cakephp validation rules and return that information to the user in a cute message box.
so i build the following (simplified):

```
$("input#UserDisplayName").keyup(function() {        
    var value = $(this).val();
    var status = validateAgainstCakeModel('display_name', value);
    var box = $("#DisplayNameMessage");

    if ( status == "true" ) {
        // show box with a message and so on ...
        var message = "This Name is available.";
        updateMessageBox( 0, box, message );
    } else {
        var message = " asdhasjkdhasd";
        updateMessageBox( 0, box, message );
    }
}
```

the validate method:

```
function validateAndUpdateMessageBox( field , value ) {
    // prepare & send ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: "register",
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 5000,
        data: { action: "validate", field: field, value: value },
        success: function( result ) {
          response = result;
        }
    });

    return response;
}
```

So the problem is the asynchronousness of the whole thing. at the time where response will be returned, there won't be any data yet and so the function will return "undefined".

yes, i know the "async: false" option, but this would lock the browser for a second (or more).
is there any other solution to code it like this and to NOT lock up the browser?

thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the code to be executed later as a callback

```
$("input#UserDisplayName").keyup(function() {        
    var value = $(this).val();
    validateAgainstCakeModel('display_name', value, function(status) {
        var box = $("#DisplayNameMessage");

        if ( status == "true" ) {
            // show box with a message and so on ...
            var message = "This Name is available.";
            updateMessageBox( 0, box, message );
        } else {
            var message = " asdhasjkdhasd";
           updateMessageBox( 0, box, message );
        }
    });
}

function validateAndUpdateMessageBox( field , value, callback ) {
    // prepare & send ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: "register",
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 5000,
        data: { action: "validate", field: field, value: value },
        success: function( result ) {
          callback.call(this, result );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after revised my answer, I modifed your structure a bit, this may be more useful if you don't want to use  `callback`

```
$("input#UserDisplayName").keyup(function() {        

var value = $(this).val();    
var box = $("#DisplayNameMessage");

$.ajax({
    url: "register",
    type: "POST",
    timeout: 5000,
    data: { action: "validate", field: 'display_name', value: value },
    success: function( result ) {
       if ( status == true ) {
            // show box with a message and so on ...
            var message = "This Name is available.";
            updateMessageBox( 0, box, message );
        } else {
            var message = " asdhasjkdhasd";
            updateMessageBox( 0, box, message );
        }            
    }
});

}
```

Comment: This won't work.  The function will return before the AJAX call is complete.  Putting the return in the callback will only return from the callback, not the main function.